# Angularjs response failed eventhough the API is called and return success

Tags: c#, angularjs, http, asp.net-web-api, xmlhttprequest

So i have this API to get the user name from domain, the API is using C#

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/authenticate")]
    public HttpResponseMessage getWinUser()
    {
        try
        {
            PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
            UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.Current;
            string displayName = user.DisplayName;

            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new ObjectContent<string>(displayName, Configuration.Formatters[0]);
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e.Message);
        }
    }
```

And I have method to call it using AngularJS

```
function getUserData() {
       return $http({
          url: 'https://localhost:44363/api/authenticate',
          method: 'GET',
          //withCredentials: true,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          }
       });
 }
```

This is where i get confused. The method calls for API is returning what I expected. Calling the endpoint from Postman also return what I need. And calling from the endpoint link directly also return as expected.
However when I call the functions from Chrome browser, it is returned as ERR:FAILED

this is the screenshot from Chrome:
[image]

What am I doing wrong and what should I use?

Comment: Is it possible that ObjectContent to return a regular string and you are waiting for a JSON?

Comment: hi DA, isn't javascript return function accepting any type of return? the function call is `return getUserData().then(function (response) {`

Comment: I see that in header the data wanted is application/json.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new ObjectContent<string>(displayName, Configuration.Formatters[0]);
        return response;
```

Can you use below :-

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,new { displayName= user.DisplayName });
```

you can then parse the **response.displayname** property in the success handler for further use.